# One While Loop Is Overwriting another While Loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, overwrite

I was making a code which will change the user input from alphabet to numbers. I made a dictionary with each alphabet as key and a corresponding number value.

In order to make the code self running (I don't have to hit run every time) I used a while loop.

```
start_over = input("Please Enter (Y) to start and (N) to stop: ").lower()

While start_over == "y" :            # First While Loop
    (the alphabet changer code here)
    start_over = input("Enter (Y) to continue and (N) to stop: ").lower()

While start_over != "y" and start_over != "n" :        # Second while loop
     start_over = input("Enter (Y) to continue and (N): ")

While start_over == "n":       #Third While Loop
      print("Thanks for using the code")
      break
```

Now the problem is when I input Y, the first while loop runs and it works properly. If I put N, the third while loop runs and the code breaks as wanted. But When I put anything except Y and N the second while loop runs and ask me to put anything else. When I put N in second while loop, the code breaks as wanted. But when I input Y in second while loop, the code breaks instead of running the first while loop. Why is this happening I have no idea.

Comment: Move your 2nd `while` before 1st `while`.

Comment: The problem with moving 2nd before 1st will save it for one time but for next time the problem will occur again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when your code enters 2nd `while` loop and user inputs `start_over = 'y'`. It won't move to your 1st `while` loop, since it is placed above. To avoid this you can put your 2nd `while` in a function:

```
def start(start_over):
    while start_over != "y" and start_over != "n" :
        start_over = input("Enter (Y) to continue and (N): ")
    return start_over

start_over = input("Please Enter (Y) to start and (N) to stop: ").lower()

if start_over != "y" and start_over != "n" :
    start_over = start(start_over)

while start_over == "y" :           
    start_over = input("Enter (Y) to continue and (N) to stop: ").lower()
    if start_over != "y" and start_over != "n" :
        start_over = start(start_over)

while start_over == "n":       #Third While Loop
      print("Thanks for using the code")
      break
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I have a question that why do we need to put the variable start_over = start(start_over). I mean can't we just call the function like start(start_over) ????

Comment: Actually the function is returning the user input i.e either `y` or `n`. To store that we have to call function like `start_over = start(start_over)`.